# Do there exist (almost surely) $C^{\infty}$-smooth Gaussian random fields?

Tags: pr.probability, fa.functional-analysis, stochastic-processes, st.statistics

Let $d \ge 1$. Do there exist Gaussian random fields on $\mathbb R^d$ which are (almost surely) $C^{\infty}$-smooth, but which are not analytic?

If so, what are necessary and sufficient conditions on the covariance function to assure that the field is (a.s.) $C^{\infty}$-smooth?

Comment: do you have anything agains taking you ananlytic field and multiplying it by a deterministic $C^{\infty}$ non-analytic function ?

Answer (score 2):

I think, you get what you want if you convolve nonsmooth trajectories (like those of a Wiener process) with a $C^\infty$ kernel that is not analytic.